# Question about the $\operatorname{Exp}$ map on $\operatorname{End}(V)$ and the left invariant vector field

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. 
We define for $T \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ with $\| T \| < \infty$
$$
\operatorname{Exp}(T) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{T^k}{k!}. 
$$
Then it can be shown that 
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \operatorname{Exp}(tT)= \operatorname{Exp}(tT)\cdot T. 
$$

Then the notes I am reading states : 
"Therefore, $t \rightarrow \operatorname{Exp}(tT)$ is tangential to the left-invariant vector field evaluated at $e$ is $T$."

I am struggling to understand this sentence here. I would appreciate if someone could explain me in more detail what this sentence means... In particular, which left-invariant vector field are they talking about?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the commutator map $$(S, T) \mapsto [S, T] := S \circ T - T \circ S$$ defines a Lie algebra structure on the vector space $\operatorname{End}(V)$ of linear maps $V \to V$. We can identify this Lie algebra with the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ of the Lie group $GL(V)$ of invertible linear transformations of $V$. (If we choose a basis of $V$, we can identify both of these with the space $M(n, \Bbb R)$ of $n \times n$ real matrices, where $n := \dim V$, endowed with the commutator $$(A, B) \mapsto A B - B A$$ of matrices.)

In particular, we can regard any linear transformation $T \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ as an element of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$, and so it determines a left-invariant vector field $\tilde T$ on $GL(V)$ characterized by $$\tilde T_1 = T .$$

Now, the map $\gamma : \Bbb R \to GL(V)$ defined by $\gamma : t \mapsto \operatorname{Exp}(t T)$ is a smooth curve in $GL(V)$, and unwinding definitions shows that it is an integral curve of $\tilde T$, that is, that $$\gamma'(t) = \tilde T_{\gamma(t)}$$ for all $t$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I'm almost getting it... Could you possibly elaborate on how to see that $End(V)$ is identified with $gl(V)$? I know that $gl(V)$ is isomorphic to the tangent space to $GL(V)$ at identity, but how do you identify this with $End(V)$? Thank you

Comment: There are a few ways to see this. One is that $GL(V)$ is an open subset of the vector space $\operatorname{End}(V)$, so we can identify $\mathfrak{gl}(V) \cong T_1 GL(V)$ with $T_1 \operatorname{End}(V)$, but for any vector space $W$ (in particular for $W = \operatorname{End}(V)$) and any $w \in W$ there is a canonical isomorphism $T_w W \cong W$. We can make this more concrete by fixing a basis of $V$, which determines isomorphisms $\operatorname{End}(V) \cong M(n, \Bbb R)$ and $GL(V) \cong GL(n, \Bbb R)$, where $n := \dim V$.